# No Module named twilio.rest

Tags: python, twilio

I have installed python 2.7.12 with PATH access and correctly installed twilio. However, when I try to execute a code I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python27\textmessage.py", line 1, in <module>
  from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
ImportError: No module named twilio.rest
```

Also, I want to know where we have to install Twilio, as I installed the Twilio library and placed it inside the `Scripts` folder.

Comment: changed the title

Comment: Please read this: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python#installation. I suggest using pip.

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* put modules into the `Scripts` folder.

To install twillio, see the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python#installation).

Answer (score 0):

Check the path. I had the same problem when I put the file send_text.py in the folder called C:\Python27\Projects. I then copy the file and placed in in the folder C:\Python27 where the libs folder is right under it. The module ran. This was a test on my system.